# Information on the .MI File Extension?

Tags: file-extension

I recently noticed the .mi file extension in the url "http://www.marriott.com/default.mi". It spawned some questions:

1. What does "MI" stand for?
2. Where is it used? What programs IO this file?
3. How is the file used in website production?

Comment: http://filext.com/file-extension/MI

Comment: http://builtwith.com/?http%3a%2f%2fwww.marriott.com%2fdefault.mi

Comment: Note that it's possible to configure most web servers to use a default extension, so the MI may mean nothing at all, or it may only mean something meaningful to Marriott.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the file name used on some random web site.

Comment: In fact, keep in mind that the concept of a "file type" does not exist on the web. "/default.mi" is simply part of the path portion of a URL. There may not even be a "default.mi" on disk anywhere.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If you still believe this Q is a off-topic, then vote again please. So that this doesn't age away.

Answer (score 26):

Per [the Mason documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason%3a%3aManual%3a%3aComponents#Component-file-extensions), the .mi extension could indicate a Mason internal component.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No sure why the down vote.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_%28Perl%29

Comment: Why would "An internal component [that] can only be accessed from other components." show up in a URL?